# getting error "Unknown BundleType: Library" while saving lightning component

Tags: lightning

I have created one lightning component, after edit component.js, saving component getting "Unknown BundleType: Library".

[image]

"Component.js Code"

```
({ 
    // this function automatic call by aura:waiting event 
    showSpinner: function(component, event, helper) {
        // make Spinner attribute true for display loading spinner 
        component.set("v.Spinner", true); 
    },    
    // this function automatic call by aura:doneWaiting event 
    hideSpinner : function(component,event,helper){
        // make Spinner attribute to false for hide loading spinner 
        component.set("v.Spinner", false);
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant component code snippet here?

Comment: ({ 
// this function automatic call by aura:waiting event 
showSpinner: function(component, event, helper) {
    // make Spinner attribute true for display loading spinner 
    component.set("v.Spinner", true); 
},    
// this function automatic call by aura:doneWaiting event 
hideSpinner : function(component,event,helper){
    // make Spinner attribute to false for hide loading spinner 
    component.set("v.Spinner", false);
}
})

Comment: I guess the error is in the .cmp file not the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error, when trying to update an existing Lightning component. My Lightning component version is 34.

I had to comment all child components that I am referring as well as "ui:outputDate" tags included in the component in order to update the component. [ "ui:outputDate" Deprecated as of API version 47.0. Use lightning:formattedDateTime instead. ]

Please let me know if you find the root cause / fix for this issue.

Thanks.
Inshar

Comment: Hi Inshar, 
My Impediments was while access lightning component using community.
Now Impediments has been fixed. 
In Community -> Setting->Security->Content Security Policy (CSP)-> select (Allow Inline Scripts).

Thanks,
Bvenkat Jeewesh